# Mudar background de A quando passar o mouse em LI

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<li class="menu-item">
<a href="http://stanlee.com.br">
<span class="jaw-menu-href-title">Home</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Quando eu passar o mouse em **li** eu quero que o *background* do **a** mude para branco.

Eu só lembro assim:

> .menu-item:hover{background:white}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz assim :

```
.menu-item:hover a span{background:white;}
```

```css
.menu-item:hover a span{background:black;}
```

```html
<li class="menu-item">
<a href="http://stanlee.com.br">
<span class="jaw-menu-href-title">Home</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul{}
ul li{}
ul li:hover a{background-color:#ccc;}
ul li a{}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <a>teste</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Não parece funcionar ;(

Comment: Funciona sim! Olha ai no JSFiddle!

Comment: Depois da edição pode ser que sim do jeito que estava não iria funcionar.